# Hiding canvas, part 2

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Gotten further along but now I can't get rid of canvaspopup, even with pack_forget().  Everything else seems to be working okay, granted I'm testing it with a very dumbed down version of the full program so I can post code here without posting 1000+ lines of code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.keys = dict.fromkeys(('Left', 'Right', 'Up', 'Down', 'Prior', 'Next', 'Shift_L', 'Alt'))

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self,bg='gray', width=1366, height=714)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, background="black", width=714, height=714)
        self.canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.canvas.place(x=652,y=0)

        self.canvas.bind("<Alt_L><w>", self.mgram)
        self.canvas.bind("<Left>", self.left)
        self.canvas.focus_set()

    def left(self,event):
        print('canvas left')
    def popleft(self,event):
        print('popup left')
    def popescape(self,event):
        self.canvas.focus_set()
        self.canvaspopup.pack_forget()

    def mgram(self,event):
        self.canvaspopup = Canvas(self, width=800, height=614)
        self.canvaspopup.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.canvaspopup.place(x=284,y=52)
        self.png = Label(self.canvaspopup)
        self.png.pack()             
        self.popupimage1 = PhotoImage(file='example.png')
        self.canvaspopup.bind("<Left>", self.popleft)
        self.canvaspopup.bind("<Escape>", self.popescape)
        self.canvaspopup.focus_set()
        self.png.config(image=self.popupimage1)
        s = Canvas(self.canvaspopup, width=800, height=14)
        s.pack_propagate(0)
        s.place(x=0,y=600)
        v = Label(s, fg='black',borderwidth=0,anchor='center',text = 'Image of: ')
        v.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

How do I make the popup disappear, supposedly in my previous question Bryan said I could use pack_forget() but that isn't working here.  Everything else seems like it working correctly.  Still not sure why I couldn't get focus_set to work earlier this morning at home.  Not sure what I've changed now???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an earlier question you asked how to hide a window managed with `pack`, and I said `pack_forget`. In this code you're using `place` so the command would be `place_forget`.

You call `pack` but immediately call `place` right after. Only one geometry manager (`pack`, `place`, `grid`) can manage a widget, and it's always the last one that you use on that widget.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I'm going to have to do a bit more research into all three methods.  I thought grid and pack were used for final 'initiation' of the object.  I didn't know place could be as well.  I thought it was just for control where on the screen the item was to be placed, not the actual 'setting' of the object.

Comment: @confused: all three serve the same purpose: to arrange the widgets on the screen.